# one_hot encoding for batches will be incomplete tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

As you know tf.one_hot can do the one hot encoding. However, when my dataset is very large, I need to do batch trainning. In this way, when i use a for loop to loop over all batches, in each iteration, when i do tf.one_hot, the dimension of one hot matrix will be smaller than i expected.

For example, for column 'a' we have 47 categories, but in one batch their might be only 20 shown, and when i do one_hot on this batch, it will create a matrix with dimension of rows * 20 instead of a dimension of rows * 47.

How to get a dimension of rows * 47 one hot matrix in each batch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) takes an argument, `depth`, as its second, that determines how long the one-hot vector should be. If you run your operation like this:

```
b = tf.one_hot( a, 47 )
```

it should give you a last dimension of 47.

Tough to say without the code, but some people don't hard code the one_hot size, but try to get it from the label tensor, with something like

```
max_class = tf.reduce_max( a )
b = tf.one_hot( a, max_class )
```

If that is the case in your code, then maybe a batch only went up to class 20.

Otherwise need to see your code to say something.

If TensorFlow is running out of memory, it will stop with an error, won't just silently bite off half of your data. :)

Comment: Thanks! I also notice this after i post this question. But it seems the category label should be start from 0 and being consecutive right? Like, if my categories are 1,5,6,8,10 and when i set it to 5 what would happen if the batch only contains 6,8,5, that may be cause mismatch right?

Comment: Not if your batch is properly randomized, then it's all over the place, that's the good way of doing it! :) If you go from class 0 to class 47 in order, it might be the case that they are consecutive, but that will yield a substandard network. Randomization is king! :)

Comment: Don't totally understand... So you mean if i set depth as 5. The data in batch will still give a matrix like this [[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]?(where the first element to fifth element in sublist represents 1,5,6,8,10 )

Comment: If you set depth to 5, then the length of the one_hot vector will be always 5. Set to 47, and it will be always 47. But be careful, the one_hot is numerically fixed, if you have for example class 10, you have to have depth of at least 10, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Ohhhhh, i get the idea now. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, happy to help! :)